# INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER

Tags: android

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw34g.png)

Hi, I got this error message everytime I try to run the app, my device run MIUI 8.
I've been looking in every single question in stackoverflow, and no answer has solved my problem.
I have all the settings right, I mean, The **`Install USB`** option is actived, both in ***security*** and in ***developer options***

**EDIT:**

I tried to run the app in another device (with MIUI 5), and it's says "Error trying to parse the package"

Comment: you have to manually confirm install on the phone screen for MIUI

Answer (score 0):

In MIUI, there is **Install apps over adb** option in **developer options**, just check that(you'll have to register for mi dev. account). Also, there will be a prompt asking whether to install the app or not, so keep your phone's screen on.

Comment: Can you confirm that **Install apps from Unknown Sources** is turned on ?

Comment: It is turned on

Comment: Yeah, I sign in

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same issue. Check the settings in developer options (install over adb and usb debugging). If still fails, try restarting the phone and Android studio. Believe me, it worked for me.

I believe this is an issue with the adb interface in MIUI.

Comment: Can you try replacing the usb cable?

Comment: I replace the usb cable, and nothing the same error

Comment: Is your miui rooted?Can you try running adb in command line and try to list the device and tell what is the device status?

Comment: No, it isn't rooted

Comment: the device is connected

Comment: It should be online.Please post a screen shot of that.

Comment: How can i know if it is online? (Sorry, I'm beginner)